# Is there a way to selectively stash in Magit without indexing?

Tags: magit

Is there a way to stash changes in magit selectively, akin to:

```
git stash save -p <paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is no, from perusing https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/magit-status.el.

It would be useful to have, might be worth opening an feature request.

Comment: Similar feature requests: [#3321](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3321) & [#3200](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3200).